# concatenate nsstring and excluding nulls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I am trying to concatenate a few NSStrings but would like to exclude the ones that are nulls. I am using this solution:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", three, two, one];
```

but what if one of the string is null? I'd like to exclude it. any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", three ?: @"", two ?: @"", one ?: @""];
```

Or better would probably be to have a mutable string and build it up:

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
if (three) {
    [string appendFormat:@"%@/", three];
}
if (two) {
    [string appendFormat:@"%@/", two];
}
if (one) {
    [string appendFormat:@"%@/", one];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just have a method like

```
- (NSString *)stringOrEmptyString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (string)
        return string;
    else
        return @"";
}
```

and then just do

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", 
    [self stringOrEmptyString:three], 
    [self stringOrEmptyString:two], 
    [self stringOrEmptyString:one]];
```

**Update:**

Alternatively, if you didn't want to have the slashes if there were blank values, you could alternatively do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (one)
    [array addObject:one];
if (two)
    [array addObject:two];
if (three)
    [array addObject:three];
```

Then you could get your NSString result with something like:

```
[array componentsJoinedByString:@"/"]
```

And, of course, if you're in a non-ARC world, you'd want a final `[array release]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a loop and check each object.

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSArray *myObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:three,two,one,nil];
for(NSString *currentObject in myObjects) {
    if(![currentObject isEqualToString:@""]) myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",myString,currentObject];
}
```

Comment: So, you're presuming that neither one, two, nor three are nil, but rather that they're all strings, possibly a string of length zero. If that's the problem he's trying to solve, then this is great. But I presumed that when moshikafya said "string is null" that he meant that the variable would be nil, in which case this wouldn't work.

Comment: If you want it to check for null instead of a blank string then just replace "![currentObject isEqualToString:@""]" with "currentObject != nil" or "currentObject"

Comment: Yeah, but then `initWithObjects`'s nil-terminated list would not work. E.g. if `two` was nil, `one` would never get added to the array. But I like your thinking about arrays, which is why I've updated my answer with another possible solution.